# How I can try Google Chrome OS?

Tags: virtualbox, google-workspace, google-chrome-os

I currently have a Windows Server 2008 R2 on my computer.

I want to try Chrome OS. Can I install it offline?

The last time I tried to install it but it doesn't work for me because I use Broadband and I am unable to get WiFi kind of thing to install it in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ChromeOS (it's basically chromium-os but it's close enough) by following this post I've wrote:
http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/chromeos-in-virtualbox-test-drive-it/
I also did a screencast in that post - so you might want to watch as well...

The problem you mention could be solved by downloading the version of ChromeOS and later you can install it in your virtualbox without a need to wifi.